# Check overlap begin and end time by group in R (Run incorrectly when data have NA)

Tags: r, data.table

This is a followup to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39049695/559784), but I've come across an issue with the answer that was provided there due to `NA`:

```
require(data.table)
ID <- c(rep(1,4), rep(3, 5), rep(4,4),rep(5,5))
Begin <- c(0,2.5,NA,3,7,8,7,25,25,10,15,0,0,1,NA,10,11,13)
End <- c(1.5,3.5,NA,6,12,8,11,29,35, 12,19,NA,28,5,20,30,20,25)
df <- data.table(ID, Begin, End)
df[, Begin_New := {
  high_so_far = shift(cummax(End), fill=Begin[1L])
  w = which(Begin < high_so_far)
  Begin[w] = high_so_far[w]
  Begin
}, by=ID]
    ID   Begin  End    Begin_New
  1:  1   0.0  1.5       0.0
  2:  1   2.5  3.5       2.5
  3:  1    NA   NA        NA
  4:  1   3.0  6.0       3.0* # <~~ it supposed 3.5
  5:  3   7.0 12.0       7.0
  6:  3   8.0  8.0      12.0
  7:  3   7.0 11.0      12.0
  8:  3  25.0 29.0      25.0
  9:  3  25.0 35.0      29.0
 10:  4  10.0 12.0      10.0
 11:  4  15.0 19.0      15.0
 12:  4   0.0   NA      19.0
 13:  4   0.0 28.0       0.0* # <~~ it's supposed 19.0
 14:  5   1.0  5.0       1.0
 15:  5    NA 20.0        NA
 16:  5  10.0 30.0      20.0
 17:  5  11.0 20.0      30.0
 18:  5  13.0 25.0      30.0
```

I try to check overlap, if Begin < End, Begin_New needs to be equal with End previous by each ID,keep checking until Begin > End, but when I have NA of End variable, the code is not understand, keep checking value. I try couple code but it doesn't work

Comment: I got it add setDT(df)[ !is.na(End), Begin_New := {
  high_so_far = shift(cummax(End), fill=Begin[1L])
  w = which(Begin < high_so_far)
  Begin[w] = high_so_far[w]
  Begin
}, by=ID]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add another step before `cummax`:

```
df[, Begin_New := {
  End[is.na(End)] = 0 # <- new step here
  high_so_far = shift(cummax(End), fill=Begin[1L])
  w = which(Begin < high_so_far)
  Begin[w] = high_so_far[w]
  Begin
}, by=ID][]
```

---

*How I got this.* To troubleshoot problems like this, I run `j` in steps for one group at a time like

```
df[, if (.GRP == 1L){
  high_so_far = shift(cummax(End), fill=Begin[1L])
  print(high_so_far)
  # w = which(Begin < high_so_far)
  # Begin[w] = high_so_far[w]
  # Begin
}, by=ID][]

# 0.0 1.5 3.5  NA
```

So I can see that this is where the problem occurs and address it by reading `?cummax` to see if there is an `na.rm` option. Not finding one there, I can think about what other step I can take before or after this one to finagle the desired result.

If I hadn't found the issue at this step, then I could gradually uncomment later lines and add more `print` statements. Or I could change `.GRP==1` to some other group. As @jangorecki mentioned, there are proper approaches to debugging you could try, too:

> you can also put `browser()` inside `j={...}` and investigate current state interactively

Comment: you can also put `browser()` inside `j={...}` and investigate current state interactively

Comment: Good option with `cummax`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @jangorecki. I've been meaning to learn how to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I should post this but @Arun posted a solution as a comment but it only works if the OP's code is run first. Arun removed his comment and didnt repost so I figured I'd post it as an answer so the OP and others see it. Feel free to give credit elsewhere.

```
library(data.table)

ID <- c(rep(1,4), rep(3, 5), rep(4,4),rep(5,5))
Begin <- c(0,2.5,NA,3,7,8,7,25,25,10,15,0,0,1,NA,10,11,13)
End <- c(1.5,3.5,NA,6,12,8,11,29,35, 12,19,NA,28,5,20,30,20,25)
df <- data.frame(ID, Begin, End)
df
setDT(df)[, Begin_New := {
  high_so_far = shift(cummax(End), fill=Begin[1L])
  w = which(Begin < high_so_far)
  Begin[w] = high_so_far[w]
  Begin
}, by=ID]

setDT(df)[!is.na(Begin) & !is.na(End), Begin_New := {
  high_so_far = shift(cummax(End), fill=Begin[1L])
  w = which(Begin < high_so_far)
  Begin[w] = high_so_far[w]
  Begin
}, by=ID]

df
    ID Begin  End Begin_New
 1:  1   0.0  1.5       0.0
 2:  1   2.5  3.5       2.5
 3:  1    NA   NA        NA
 4:  1   3.0  6.0       3.5
 5:  3   7.0 12.0       7.0
 6:  3   8.0  8.0      12.0
 7:  3   7.0 11.0      12.0
 8:  3  25.0 29.0      25.0
 9:  3  25.0 35.0      29.0
10:  4  10.0 12.0      10.0
11:  4  15.0 19.0      15.0
12:  4   0.0   NA      19.0
13:  4   0.0 28.0      19.0
14:  5   1.0  5.0       1.0
15:  5    NA 20.0        NA
16:  5  10.0 30.0      10.0
17:  5  11.0 20.0      30.0
18:  5  13.0 25.0      30.0
```

Comment: Yeah, so add the same code like that with !is.na(Begin) & !is.na(End), it works

Comment: Oh no, row 16 needs to be 20